# How to resolve Android class issues: android.Manifest$permission and android.R?

Tags: android

I have updated software and ADT in my Eclipse a number of times. I am unable to run projects above than 1.5.I have the following errors showing up in my console window after i create a HelloWorld project with API Level 4 (1.6):

```
[2010-04-04 22:21:53 - Framework Resource Parser] Collect resource IDs failed, class android.R not found in E:\Android\android-sdk_r04-windows\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-1.6\android.jar
[2010-04-04 22:21:53 - Framework Resource Parser] Collect permissions failed, class android.Manifest$permission not found in E:\Android\android-sdk_r04-windows\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-1.6\android.jar
[2010-04-04 22:21:54 - Android Framework Parser] failed to collect preference classes
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I had this error and I did the next steps in order to solve:

1. Make a clean.
2. Restart the machine (Probably not necessary)
3. Delete a string in the strings.xml that I did not use any more.

After that, doing a build, the R class was regenerated and the project builded without errors.